# How I can fix Close()?

Tags: c#, forms, file

I´m trying to write a code that will refer to form1, while testing my procedure I started the code to see if everything worked. Everything worked so I wanted to close the windows that were supposed to close by clicking on any cross. When I click on cross ysstem wrote me error message: *An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll* and referred to `Close()`

Form1:

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace adresar
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private Form2 form2;
        static string folderPath = string.Empty;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            
        }

        private void Form1_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            form2 = new Form2();
            form2.FormClosed += new FormClosedEventHandler(form2_FormClosed);
            form2.Data = "";
            form2.Location = new Point(Location.X, Location.Y + Height + 80);
            form2.Show();
            textBox1.Focus();
        }
         void form2_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
        {
           Close();
        }
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            
            var folder = new FolderBrowserDialog();

            if (folder.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                folderPath = Path.GetFullPath(folder.SelectedPath);
                textBox1.Text = folderPath;
            }            
        }     
    }
}
```

Form2:

```
    using System;
    using System.Windows.Forms;
    
    namespace adresar
            {
                public partial class Form2 : Form
                {
                    public string Data
                    { 
                        get { return richTextBox1.Text; }
                        set { richTextBox1.Text = "Adresář:" + Environment.NewLine + "Soubor:"; }
                    }
                    public Form2()
                    {
                        InitializeComponent();
                     
                    }
                }
            }
```

Does anyone know what to do about it?
[image: this is the error]

Comment: Did you try to use `this.Close()`?

Comment: @kosist yes did´t help

Comment: @sloth always the same

Comment: Your code works fine. You need to provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your issue.

Comment: @Enigmativity that's the exact code

Comment: @dejf111 - Then you need to give us the exact steps required to replicate the error. Start with a fresh project and go from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This Error can happen because your form1 wants to close before form2 is closed and since your form 1 refers to form2 it calls close there again and results in a endless loop. A simple fix would be using Application.Exit(); instead of close();

Comment: okey I try new Project file

Comment: I create new project file with the same result

Answer (score 0):

I recreated your code with this:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private Form2 form2;
    private void Form1_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        form2 = new Form2();
        form2.FormClosed += new FormClosedEventHandler(form2_FormClosed);
        form2.Location = new Point(Location.X, Location.Y + Height + 80);
        form2.Show();
        textBox1.Focus();
    }
    void form2_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
    {
        Close();
    }
}
```

`Form2` was just a blank form.

It behaved normally. Closing either form worked just fine.

I put in the rest of your code and it still worked.

You haven't provided us with the code that demonstrates your issue.

Comment: When I copied your code it still doesn't work